# How is generic list manipulation function written?

Tags: c, function, generic-list

I am a beginner in programming, please go easy on me and I am finding difficult to get the answer for my question. I can't get my head around the complex codes. Can some one please explain me with simple coding of how is `generic list manipulation function written which accepts elements of any kind?` Thanks in advance.

Comment: C is not a very good language for generic programming unfortunately

Comment: This [BOOK](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) may help you lot, also a [code](http://www.linuxcandy.com/2011/11/week-4-introduction-to-generic.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is normally done using void pointers:

```
typedef struct node {
  struct node *next;
  void *data;
} node;

node *insert(node *list, void *data) {
}

node *delete(node *list, node *to_delete) {
}
```

such manipulation functions do not depend on the actual type of data so they can be implemented generically. For example you can have a data type struct for the data field above:

```
typedef struct data {
  int type;
  void *data;
} data;

/* .... */
data d;
d.type = INT;
d.data = malloc(sizeof(int));
node n = {NULL, (void*)&data);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need a heterogenous list. Some pointers below:

Make the data element of the list node as a generic structure, which contains an indicator for data type and data.

```
    /** This should be your data node **/
    struct nodedata
    {
      int datatype;
      void *data;
    };    

    /** This should be your list node **/
    struct listnode
    {
      struct nodedata *data;
      struct listnode *next;
    };
```

Using the above structure, you can store different types of data.
Use function pointers for comparison functions or invoke different functions depending upon the data type.